# Logging %pre during kickstart - logfile doesn't exist after boot

Tags: rhel, logs, kickstart

I am kickstarting several EL6 systems and I want to log the actions taken in my `%pre` section.

I know that I can log the `%post` section per the hints provided by [centos.org: Tips and tricks for anaconda and kickstart](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/KickStart#head-e5b66179e35dc60613de0e6518e336cb5353cbd7) using one of these two methods:

```
%post --log=/root/my-post-log
echo 'Hello, World!'
```

Or:

```
%post
exec < /dev/tty3 > /dev/tty3
chvt 3
echo
echo "################################"
echo "# Running Post Configuration   #"
echo "################################"
(
echo 'Hello, World!'
) 2>&1 | /usr/bin/tee /var/log/post_install.log
chvt 1
```

However I can't get this to work with the `%pre` section. Here is what I'm using:

```
%pre --log=/var/log/my-pre-log
echo 'Hello, World!'
```

When I am finally allowed to use the [Virtual Consoles](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/KickStart#line-43), the logfile is not to be found anywhere on the system.

This works fine for the `%post` section because at the time `%post` is executed, Anaconda switches to the new disks using `chroot`-- `/var/log/` actually exists on the new system, and thus the logfile will exist after a reboot.

The problem with doing this with the `%pre` section is that the only filesystems available at the time is the memory-only filesystem. If I write the file to `/tmp/`, `/root/pre_install.log` or `/var/log` the filesystem disappears as soon as I shut down the machine.

The debugging shell is [not available until midway through the installation](https://serverfault.com/a/322395/36178), which makes debugging difficult.

Comment: I can't verify this in my current environment, but would **syslog=<host>[:<port>]

    Once installation is up and running, send log messages to the syslog process on <host>, and optionally, on port <port>. Requires the remote syslog process to accept connections (the -r option). **  suffice?

Comment: That might be a reasonable workaround as we do have a syslog server. Will kickstart send both STDERR & STDOUT to syslog, because I'd want both for debugging.

Comment: What if you write the file to `/tmp/my-pre-log` in `%pre`, and then when you're in the `%post` write the file to `/root/my-pre-log`?

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same need as you, to capture the `%pre` log for later analysis. You're right, by the time you're in `%post` Anaconda has already chrooted you to the newly-built filesystem, so it's not possible to access the `%pre` log. You could run `%post` with `--nochroot`, but IMO that makes paths in `%post` a pain.

I managed to get what I wanted by using `%include` inside the `%post` section. First, log your `%pre` output:

```
%pre --log /tmp/pre-install.log
echo "Starting Kickstart Pre-Installation..."
```

Then `%include` the `%pre` log during `%post`, sending it to a file with a bash here document :

```
%post --log /root/post-install.log
cat >> /root/pre-install.log << "EOF"
%include /tmp/pre-install.log
EOF
```

I believe this works because the `%pre` section gets evaluated by Anaconda first, which allows you to create files to be used by `%include`... then Anaconda evaluates the rest of the file, replacing each `%include` with the named file. I'm also capturing the Anaconda log the same way, just replaces `pre-install` with `anaconda` in the two `%post` section lines.