# Differences between %pre and %post in Kickstart on CentOS?

Tags: centos, scripting, kickstart

I have been setting up machines with Kickstart on CentOS and I am unsure about the differences between the `%pre` and `%post` sections of the kickstart `.cfg` file.

The CentOS Documentation for the [Pre-Installation Script](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-kickstart2-preinstallconfig.html) states:

```
You can add commands to run on the system immediately after the ks.cfg has been parsed.
```

While the section for the [Post-Installation Script](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-kickstart2-postinstallconfig.html) states:

```
You have the option of adding commands to run on the system once the installation is complete.
```

After also reading [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78388/logging-pre-during-kickstart-logfile-doesnt-exist-after-boot), i notice that the `%pre` section does not seem to have access to the file system in some way.

My question(s) are:

- What are the differences between `%pre` and `%post` sections of a kickstart script in CentOS?
- Is the `%pre` section run concurrently with the kickstart script (after parsing)?
- Is there persistent storage available during the `%pre` section of the kickstart script?

Comment: The links to CentOS docs are broken.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- What are the differences between %pre and %post sections of a kickstart script in CentOS?

The `%pre` section runs prior to when anaconda evaluates the rest of the kickstart file, after the second stage of the installer has started.  This means that you can create files in `%pre` that can be included with a `%include /tmp/somefile` in the kickstart configuration.   `%post` runs after package installation and bootloader setup has completed.

- Is the %pre section run concurrently with the kickstart script (after parsing)?

The RHEL documentation says the %pre is executed after the kickstart is parsed, but can dynamically create additional content to the kickstart through %include statements. https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-preinstallconfig.html

- Is there persistent storage available during the %pre section of the kickstart script?

Typically, you use a writable /tmp directory in `%pre`, which is not persistent to the resulting OS.  It's just a ramdisk.  `%post` runs chrooted into the new install root, or it can run in the root of anaconda (with `%post --nochroot`), where you can access the files you might have created/saved during `%pre`.

Comment: how do you know it runs prior to parsing. where are you seeing that information?

Comment: What I wrote was poorly written.  As the RHEL documentation says, the %pre is executed after the kickstart is parsed, but can dynamically create additional content to the kickstart through %include statements. https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-preinstallconfig.html

Comment: if you change the answer to reflect this, I will choose your answer.