# Can I create files in kickstart %pre, then later access those same files during RPM package installation and/or kickstart %post?

Tags: rpm, kickstart

I read the post [Differences between %pre and %post in Kickstart on CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115213/differences-between-pre-and-post-in-kickstart-on-centos), which includes the following statement:
`%post` runs chrooted into the new install root, or it can run in the root of anaconda (with `%post --nochroot`), where you can access the files you might have created/saved during `%pre`.

How can these files be accessed, exactly?
Can I access these files (which were created during %pre) in an RPM package %post scriptlet?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Kickstart and RPM are different beasts.
%pre and %post section of Kickstart is totally different from %pre and %post of RPM package. They have the same name, more or less similar purpose (doing something before and after), but are part of different objects.

If you want to save/restore state between %pre and %post in RPM package then see: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets#Saving_state_between_scriptlets